# How to check condition for razor ternary operator to string

Tags: c#, html, razor

```
<input type="text" class="date" value="@item.MarksEntryLastDate.Equals("01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM") ? @System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"): @item.MarksEntryLastDate  />
```

Hi friends, I am new to the mvc framework. Please help me to use the condition for razor ternary operator in cshtml.

Comment: Why not just perform ternary operator checking in the controller side? Try shorten it to `<input type="text" class="date" value=@item.MarksEntryLastDate />` and in controller action method use this: `MarksEntryLastDate = MarksEntryLastDate.Equals("01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM") ? DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy") : MarksEntryLastDate`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put brackets around the whole `@`:

```
<input type="text" class="date" value="@(item.MarksEntryLastDate.Equals("01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM") ? System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy") : item.MarksEntryLastDate)"  />
```

**Edit**

As Esko points out, you may be better comparing to a date rather than a string:

```
item.MarksEntryLastDate.Equals(System.DateTime.MinValue)
```

Comment: Correct, might also be good practice to use DateTime.MinValue instead of the string comparison.

Comment: @Esko Yeah, I was thinking you would need to compare a date rather than a string, but wasn't sure